# what starts runsv on a Debian system using init and how?

Tags: debian, git, init.d, sysvinit

A bit of background: I installed `git-daemon-run` on a Debian system, and now git-daemon starts at boot automatically, even though there is no init script for it in `/etc/init.d`.

I did some digging and found out that this particular daemon is managed by `runsv` and the `sv` utility, an alternative to the `init` scheme. Yet I cannot find anywhere a script or a command that tells runsv to start at boot.

How does `runsv` start? How can I disable it starting at boot, so that I can turn on and off the `git-daemon` service at will?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know `sv`, but if it's anything like other `init` replacements, it ignores `/etc/init.d` and you configure it by some other means. Also, if it really is an `init` replacement, then the *kernel* runs it, so you won't find any script that starts it.

I recommend having a dig through the manpages to figure out how to configure it to do what you want it to do. (E.g., configure get-daemon to start at boot.)